# Installation step fails: docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate: unable to connect to DB

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Kiwi version: 7.2
I am running a CentOS 8 VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host.

The basic problem seems to be that kiwi_web cannot connect to kiwi_db.

When I run the command:

```
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
```

I get the error (full response at the end):

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
```

I also get this error if I log into kiwi_web and run "/Kiwi/manage.py migrate".

I get the same error when I run the createsuperuser command:

```
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py createsuperuser
```

After adding mysql command line to kiwi_web, when I run:

```
mysql -h kiwi_db -u kiwi -p
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'kiwi_db' (113)
```

Same error if I use different hostnames such as kiwi_db or the IP address.

I don't think I deviated from the instructions at https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html during the installation, except that I tried to open the Kiwi page and got the 500 internal server error before running the migrate command.

Any ideas on how to get past this?

Thanks,

..Ron

Data:

The full response when I run the command is:

```
# docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
```

And full response from createsuperuser command:

```
# docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 363, in execute
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and happy new year first.

> I am running a CentOS 8 VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host.

Do you mean to say that you have Docker running inside the CentOS VM or not ?

> The basic problem seems to be that kiwi_web cannot connect to kiwi_db.

Assuming Docker is running inside the VM and you are trying to run the Kiwi TCMS container then:

- Does `docker-compose up` bring the 2 containers up? Can you verify that they are present, e.g. `docker ps` ?

> ... I tried to open the Kiwi page and got the 500 internal server error before running the migrate command.

- The 500 here is likely because there is no database (no tables, no connection, something else). If you were seing a Kiwi TCMS branded error page or anything at all that means `kiwi_web` container is running.  Can you verify that this container is running ?  You should be redirected to https://localhost (or FQDN, IP address) and the page should be using our own self-signed SSL certificate. Is this the case ?

Everything that you've shown looks like you've got the web container running but not the database container running ? You can try to `docker exec ... /bin/bash` for each of the containers to make sure they are there.  If that happens then try any networking tools for Linux (e.g. ping, netstat) to see if there is a network connectivity between the two containers. They should be on the same virtual network (in Docker terms) and their names should also serve as host names on that same network.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am running Docker inside the CentOS VM. Both containers are running. I am able to log into each of them and ping each from the other. I am able to log into the DB server as user "kiwi" when logged into the kiwi_db container. When I show tables in the kiwi DB, no tables are listed. So the problem is still that when I log into the kiwi_web container and run the migrate command, I get the error 2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)" even though I can ping db from kiwi_web.

Comment: So does `docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate` also results in the same error?  If yes this means the Django app can't connect to the DB server, which it tries to do so with the provided credentials. Have you altered settings perhaps or rebuild the Docker image? What is the image hash you are using (e.g. post docker images | grep kiwi)

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I was doing was setting up a preliminary eval environment on my desktop/VM so that I could provide the IT group with info they need to set up the working environment. They've since set up that server and did not encounter the problem I was having. So, this problem is moot at this point. :) Again, thank you very much for taking the time to help me!